# Blank result in Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Every time I do an Ajax request, I want server to check if number is 1, 3 or 5, and depending on result, echo out answer. The problem is, I get no `data` in my `alert();`. Here's my code:

ajax:

```
ajaxNumber= $.ajax({
            url: "operations.php",
            type: "post",
            data: ile,
            success: function(data){alert(data);}
        });
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['ile'])) {
  $numer = intval($_POST['ile']);
  if($numer==1|$numer==3|$numer==5) {
  echo "ok";
 } else {
  echo "ERROR";
 }
}
```

`alert();` is being displayed, but it's just empty.

[image]

**EDIT:** Running `operations.php` on my own and giving $_POST['ile'] an existing value echos out me good responses.

Comment: what's the value of `ile`?

Comment: @KevinYan a number. It can be 1, 3 or 5. This ajax is part of function which begins with `function downBy(ile) {`

Comment: No, you can't pass 1, 3, 5 literally and get them in php through `$_POST['ile']` @Kajcioch

Comment: @KevinYan oh. Why?

Comment: Eh, I will give you the right code, and explain it.

Comment: And see this line here, `if($numer==1|$numer==3|$numer==5) {`, `|` is bitwise OR and `||` is logical OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't set *ile* name so $_POST['ile'] is empty, try this :

```
ajaxNumber= $.ajax({
        url: "operations.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {'ile':ile},
        success: function(data){alert(data);}
    });
```

Comment: Oh, now I see my mistake. I defined `ile` but I didn't give it any value. Thanks for solving this out for me!

Comment: @Kajcioch your welcome , would you please mark it as true answer

Comment: I always do, I just gotta wait a couple of minutes. @Ali

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't pass `ile` with value 1, 3 or 5 literally.

Change your code like below:

```
var ile = 1;// just a example so I assign 1 to variable `ile`
var postData = {'ile': ile};
$.ajax({
    url: "operations.php",
    type: "post",
    data: postData,
    success: function(response){
       alert(response);
    }
});
```

JQuery documentation says data is

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string.
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array

So that's why you can't send 1, 3 or 5 directly, its supposed to be a object like `{name1: value, name2: value2}` or a query string like `'name1=value1&name2=value2'`

***EDIT***

See your php code, in `if` condition please use logic OR `||` like the other guy said in the comment.